# How do completely disable signed assemblies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a VS.NET 2010 solution with several projects.  I just added a new library project (the.library.assembly).  The startup project is a website.  When I run the website, I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'the.library.assembly' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

Where does this come from?  I haven't been using signed assemblies with other projects and they work fine.

--- EDIT ---

Actually, I did find that the.library.assembly was signed.  This was related to trouble shooting the signed issue. I have unchecked that in project properties and gone through all projects in the solution.  None are signed.  I get the build error now:

```
Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'the.library.assembly' does not have a strong name.
```

I thought maybe this was related to a WCF service the.library.assembly was referencing.  I removed the service and related code.  Everything built fine.  I added the service back.  Another good build.  I added service related code back to the.library.assembly.  Still builds.  Then I added the.library.assembly calls into the web app.  That's when I get the above build failure.

Comment: The assembly was likely signed with a non-trusted certificate. I would sign it with a valid certificate, or just not signed it, of course you either need to do ALL signed or NO signed assemblies.

Comment: I've added some additional details in the OP.  Everything is non signed now but the build fails.

Answer (score 1):

I found entries referencing signing in the web app's AssemblyInfo.cs.  Commenting those out allowed the solution to build.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In my case, I found three signing related lines which I removed from AssemblyInfo.cs: `[assembly: AssemblyDelaySign(false)]` `[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("....")]` `[assembly: AssemblyKeyName("")]`